# Voting system using PHP, MySQL and jQuery - NOT working (DIAGNOSE)

Tags: jquery, ajax, voting

Trying to make this **[Reddit-style Voting With PHP, MySQL And jQuery](http://www.technabled.com/2009/02/reddit-style-voting-with-php-mysql-and.html) work**.

**Problem:** When I click **"Vote up"** or **"Vote down"**, it doesn't return anything. Nothing happens on the page, at all.
*I have established that the `votes.php` page is working though,* but can't figure out why the rest is not.

Basically, there are 3 sets of codes:
**01.** jQuery scripts that goes into the <`head`>,
**02.** html inside the <`body`> (displays: voting buttons and results) / `index.php`...
**03.** the PHP page (`votes.php`) where jquery sends the action to.

---

**01.)** Placed within my <`head`>:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://site.com/js/jquery.pack.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("a.vote_up").click(function(){
    //get the id
    the_id = $(this).attr('id');

    // show the spinner
    $(this).parent().html("<img src='images/spinner.gif'/>");

    //fadeout the vote-count 
    $("span#votes_count"+the_id).fadeOut("fast");

    //the main ajax request
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: "action=vote_up&id="+$(this).attr("id"),
            url: "votes.php",
            success: function(msg)
            {
                $("span#votes_count"+the_id).html(msg);
                //fadein the vote count
                $("span#votes_count"+the_id).fadeIn();
                //remove the spinner
                $("span#vote_buttons"+the_id).remove();
            }
        });
    });


    $("a.vote_down").click(function(){
    //get the id
    the_id = $(this).attr('id');

    // show the spinner
    $(this).parent().html("<img src='images/spinner.gif'/>");

    //the main ajax request
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: "action=vote_down&id="+$(this).attr("id"),
            url: "votes.php",
            success: function(msg)
            {
$("span#votes_count"+the_id).fadeOut().html(msg).fadeIn();
                $("span#vote_buttons"+the_id).remove();
            }
        });
    });
}); 
</script>
```

---

**02.)** Placed within the **loop** inside <`body`>:
(Voting buttons & where results should show)

```php
<div class=\"entry\">
 <span class=\"votes_count\" id=\"votes_count" .$id. "\">" .$effective_vote. " votes</span>  

 <span class=\"vote_buttons\" id=\"vote_buttons" .$id. "\">  
  <a href=\"javascript:;\" class=\"vote_up\" id=\"" .$id. "\">Vote Up!</a>  
  <a href=\"javascript:;\" class=\"vote_down\" id=\"" .$id. "\">Vote Down!</a>  
 </span>  

</div>
```

---

**03.)** My `votes.php` page (where the action happens):

```sql
// Database connection here //

function getAllVotes($id)
    {
    $votes = array();
    $q = "SELECT * FROM cover WHERE id='$id' ";
    $r = mysql_query($q) or die("Error: ". mysql_error(). " with query ". $q);
    if(mysql_num_rows($r)==1) {

        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r);
        $votes[0] = $row['votes_up'];
        $votes[1] = $row['votes_down'];
        }
    return $votes;
    }

function getEffectiveVotes($id)
    {
    /**
    Returns an integer
    **/
    $votes = getAllVotes($id);
    $effectiveVote = $votes[0] - $votes[1];
    return $effectiveVote;
    }

$id = $_POST['id'];
$action = $_POST['action'];

//get the current votes
$cur_votes = getAllVotes($id);

//ok, now update the votes

if($action=='vote_up') //voting up
{
    $votes_up = $cur_votes[0]+1;
    $q = "UPDATE cover SET votes_up = $votes_up WHERE id = $id";
}
elseif($action=='vote_down') //voting down
{
    $votes_down = $cur_votes[1]+1;
    $q = "UPDATE cover SET votes_down = $votes_down WHERE id = $id";
}

$r = mysql_query($q);
if($r) //voting done
    {
    $effectiveVote = getEffectiveVotes($id);
    echo $effectiveVote." votes";
    }
elseif(!$r) //voting failed
    {
    echo "Failed!";
    }
```

---

Specifically, what I especially like about this compared to other rating methods provided online, is that it returns the sum total number of votes (subtracts # of vote-downs from vote-ups, and returns that value).

I do not do a lot of jQuery or ajax, it confuses me at times, but I have very basic simple knowledge. (I usually just follow the codes)

**+ Also, how do I make this into a PDO version**, rather than using MySQL Queries? I would appreciate it if someone could additionally help with this. **:o)**

Not sure how to notify a user on StackOverflow, but the developer of this project was:
User: **abhisek**  (*user: 4507330*)

Thanks for your time! Hopefully, someone can diagnose the source of the problem.

Comment: Please try to ask one question with one code sample and one answer.

Comment: I bet your ajax call is getting cached in the browser.

Comment: @asawyer: POST requests are never cached.

Comment: @minitech : My post's question is: `Problem: When I click "Vote up" or "Vote down", it doesn't return anything. Nothing happens on the page, at all.` And I attached the **3 codes** provided, which are possible sources of the problem. I can't figure out which one of them is the problem though.

Comment: @Love do you see any errors in your browsers console?

Comment: @bPratik : Exactly how do I check this bPratik? On my browser itself, there are no problems, or errors, when I click on the voting buttons. The page just looks like it ignored or doesn't know about the click/vote.

Comment: @Love which browser are you using? Chrome, for instance, shows all exceptions (including syntax errors) on the console. Firefox omits some (for instance, doesn't show if there is a syntax error, even with Firebug - just doesn't load the script, so you can't find it in the "scripts" list). Dunno about other browsers.

Comment: @mgibsonbr : I both have Chrome and Firefox open right now, & doing checking on both. I don't know how to check for browser errors though, but there's nothing happening that is out of the ordinary for my browsers, it doesn't seem like I'm having any errors.

Comment: @minitech Hmm got me there don't you.

Comment: Are you testing on your local machine, by any chance? I smell an origin control issue here.

Comment: @Love on Chrome, press **F12** to bring up developer tools. In there you'll find the `Console`

Comment: @vzwick how exactly? I've tested local `PHP` + `AJAX` setup without issues? Maybe I'm missing something!

Comment: @Love can you host this setup online? Maybe a dummy server where we can test, as it is too late in the night for me to be bothered setting up a workbench!

Comment: @vzwick : I am checking using my computer, if that is what a local machine is. :)

@bPratik : Thanks, I saw this error **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'click' of null** here:
`$(function(){
 $("a.vote_up").click(function(){
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'click' of null
 //get the id
 the_id = $(this).attr('id');`

Comment: @bPratik - `localhost` is considered a non-origin by most browsers out there. At least for remote calls - not sure about those to localhost itself right now.

Comment: @Love do you by any chance have other frameworks in the same page besides jQuery? (ex. prototype.js) `$(something)` should **never** be `null`. I see the main function is being called, or the code wouldn't reach that point to raise that error. Try explicitly using `jQuery.click` instead of `$.click` and see what happens.

Comment: I saw this error **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'click' of null** here:  
`$(function(){
 $("a.vote_up").click(function(){
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'click' of null
 //get the id
 the_id = $(this).attr('id');`  

When I click on the error to collapse:  
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'click' of null index.php:6
(anonymous function) index.php:6
o.extend.ready.o.readyList jquery.pack.js:19
o.extend.each jquery.pack.js:12
o.extend.ready jquery.pack.js:19
o.each.o.fn.(anonymous function)`

Comment: @mgibsonbr : Yes, as a matter of fact on my header I, as well, have: `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.0.0/prototype.js"></script>`  

I replaced **$.click** with **jQuery.click**, and the error that shows up is: `Uncaught TypeError: Object javascript:; has no method 'attr' `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery and prototype.js in the same page, you need to be careful about how you use the `$` function (since both frameworks claim that name). One option is replacing your main function with:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    ...
});
```

This way you'll be able to use `$` as an alias for `jQuery` inside that block (but you won't be able to access prototype.js though). Another option is to use jQuery's [`noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/). Check the docs for more information about how to use it.

Comment: Thank you! Removed `prototype.js` and it now works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You may like this Jquery Ajax Voting system

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>  
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".voteMe").click(function() {
        var voteId = this.id;
        var upOrDown = voteId.split('_'); 
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "<?= base_url();?>/index.php/article/voteMe",
            cache: false,               
            data:'voteId='+upOrDown[0] + '&upOrDown=' +upOrDown[1],
            success: function(response){
                try{
                    if(response=='true'){   
                        var newValue = parseInt($("#"+voteId+'_result').text()) + 1;            
                        $("#"+voteId+'_result').html(newValue);
                    }else{
                        alert('Sorry Unable to update..');
                    }
                }catch(e) {     
                    alert('Exception while request..');
                }       
            },
            error: function(){                      
                alert('Error while request..');
            }
         });
    });

});
</script>
<style>
ul,ol,li{
    list-style-type: none;
}

h2{
    color: #2864B4;
    text-decoration: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<?php
    if(is_array($VOTES) && count($VOTES) ) {
?>
<div>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach($VOTES as $loop){ ?>               
        <li>
        <div>
            <h2><?=$loop->VOTE_DESC;?></h2>
            <span><a id="<?=$loop->VOTE_ID;?>_upvote" class="voteMe"><img src="<?= base_url();?>/img/images/up_vote.png"/></a><span id="<?=$loop->VOTE_ID;?>_upvote_result" ><?=$loop->UP_VOTE;?></span></span>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
            <a id="<?=$loop->VOTE_ID;?>_downvote" class="voteMe"><img src="<?= base_url();?>/img/images/down_vote.png"/></a><span id="<?=$loop->VOTE_ID;?>_downvote_result" ><?=$loop->DOWN_VOTE;?></span>
        </div>
        </li>
    <?php }?>   
    </ul>
</div>
<?php }?>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```